# Debugging a console application that crashes from drag-n-drop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, console-application

I built a console application that allows users to drag and drop files on to it and it will process it. However, it crashes while it's processing the file and I don't know what's going on.

How can I debug this? The console closes too fast for me to see what the issue was, and I can't reproduce the error when I call it through command-line and specify some args there.

The procedure is as follows

- In windows explorer, I drag my input file (an image) over an exe
- The exe would then read the image and do something with it
- I then save the image in a new file

The crash occurs during the saving, but I am not too interested in where the issue is, but the fact that I can't come up with a way to actually debug this properly.

Comment: Can you please add more details about how you do drag'n drop, what you do drop and what you are going to do with the dropped object(s)

Comment: I have added details, although I am not sure why it is necessary to know what I am doing. I'm not looking for a solution to the crashing, I'm looking for a solution on how to debug the crash. I have an idea what's going on but that was because I was commenting out code to pinpoint exactly where it was occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is started automatically by some other program (like explorer) - configure [Launch debugger on process start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx).

Another simple way (when tweaking registry is not an option) is to add [Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) in your code to have chance to attache debugger. Or even Thread.Sleep(10000) to give you chance to catch it.

There is nothing very specific about drag-n-drop (unlike focus issues that often require remote debugging).

Either start application form VS with correct parameter or attach to running appliction. You may want to turn on "Debug->Exception->break when thrown" for CLR exceptions (may need to disable "Tools->Options->Debug->My code only").

Watch output window while attached to the process for any suspicious traces.

If VS is getting in a way you can use WinDbg the same way... But try VS route first before.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify you're debugging command lines in the project propertys just like

[image: Visual Studio 2012 with the debug time event args]

then you can place your breakpoints like you would do usually and debug your app.

Comment: Is this the same effect as opening cmd and passing in args to my application? Because the issue specifically occurs when I perform a drag and drop.

Comment: Yes this will place the four values into your command lines args (such from `public static void Main(string[] args)` or `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` just like if you start your app from the cmd shell.

Comment: I have just tried it. The application processed everything successfully in debug mode. Then I built it, dragged the same file over the exe, and it crashed.

Comment: then there must be another issue. please edit your quetion and add relevant code where the app crashes.

Comment: also please add the args theirself to the question

Comment: It is a general question asking how I can debug apps that crash from drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you tried everything Alexei Levenkov mentioned, if that doesn't work to you (which likely will only happen if you are doing things wrong somehow) you could also use a **simple logfile** to trace the error, but I would *always* go with the VS debugger, since thats mutch more confortable.